# Apereo CAS 6.0.x - Auto-login after registration

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, cas

I use CAS 6.0.x with OAuth 2.0. I have an external app to register new user. 
In one of my flow, I want to auto-login user in CAS after successfully registration.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use [JWT Authentication](https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.0.x/installation/JWT-Authentication.html). Basically, you create a JWT token and pass it along to CAS; once unpacked and validated, CAS should create an SSO session and log the user in automatically.